# How to access stateSnapshot in mapGroupsWithState or share the GroupState between streams?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

With the DStream API it's possible to access the snapshot state of a stateful stream using [MapWithStateDStream.stateSnapshots()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MapWithStateDStream@stateSnapshots():org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[(KeyType,StateType)]). In the new Structured Streaming API it seems to me that only the function passed to mapGroupsWithState is able to access and update the state.

I'd like to create an in-memory distributed state of a stream based on it's input events. Then enrich events from another stream by joining them to the first event's **(complete) state**, i.e. not to the first stream itself.

Using the DStream API I'd simply join the second stream with the first stream's stateSnapshot. Is this feature missing on the new Structured Streaming API or is there a new better/cleaner way of **sharing** the `GroupState` between two streams this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this feature missing on the new Structured Streaming API or is
>   there a new better/cleaner way of doing this?

There is no `stateSnapshot` provided out of the box as part of Structured Streaming (SS). I'm assuming this could be done, perhaps in a later version of SS. I'm not sure it fits their design goals, since state is completely masked away from the end user for arbitrary streams, although this could be useful for people using custom state via `(flat)mapGroupsWithState`.

In order to roll your own "snapshot", you can always output the intermediate state you have in `GroupState[S]` at for every batch generated, i.e:

```
def updateSessionEvents(
  id: Int,
  userEvents: Iterator[UserEvent],
  state: GroupState[UserSession]): Option[UserSession] = {
    // Do stuff
    val someState = ??? // update state
    someState
}
```

Then, you're exposed to the entire state all the time. What this means is that you'll now need to maintain some flag indicating if the state is actually complete or not, in order not to send incomplete state downstream where it isn't mean to be.

Comment: What happens with the `GroupState[S]` events once `(flat)mapGroupsWithState` pushes them down? Aren't they simply buffered for the windowDuration and then dropped? Is it possible to update given entry within the "pushed down" state? For example with DStream.stateSnapshot() I could update the snapshot based on incoming events for that stream. Later on when the snapshot is joined with the second stream, then the new (updated entry) data will be used. The snapshot concept fits perfectly here and I hope there's a way to do the same with Structured Streaming API.

Answer (score 0):

`mapGroupsWithState` is like the functional `map` where for every input you **have to** give an output. That's the contract of `map` in its broad sense and `mapGroupsWithState` follows it.

If I understood you correctly, what you really need is [KeyValueGroupedDataset.flatMapGroupsWithState](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset@flatMapGroupsWithState[S,U](outputMode:org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode,timeoutConf:org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.GroupStateTimeout)(func:(K,Iterator[V],org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.GroupState[S])=%3EIterator[U])(implicitevidence$9:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[S],implicitevidence$10:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) as you seem to be building a so-called **arbitrary stateful stream aggregation**.

> **flatMapGroupsWithState[S, U](outputMode: OutputMode, timeoutConf: GroupStateTimeout)(func: (K, Iterator[V], GroupState[S]) ⇒ Iterator[U])(implicit arg0: Encoder[S], arg1: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]** applies the given function to each group of data, while maintaining a user-defined per-group state.

This seemingly complex `flatMapGroupsWithState` function gives you the most powerful abstraction for stateful aggregations and my understanding is that if it's not capable of giving you the expected result it's unlikely there's a better function (I'd love being told that I'm wrong).

Comment: Well, according to the documentation the difference between mapGroupsWithState and flatMapGroupsWithState is that the latter can output multiple values for single input. Nevertheless both of them operate only on the events for the batch interval. What I want to achieve is to access the RDD (or DataFrame) of the whole GroupState and join it with the events from a another stream. If I'd simply join with the output of (flat)mapGroupsWithState then I'll be joining only against the output of the batch interval output and not the whole state.

Comment: @AleksandarKanchev did you ever figure out a way to solve this problem? I'm facing a similar issue. I need to lookup values from events stream in the GroupState DF and figure out whether they have an existing state in the second stream. Thanks!