# Spark Documentation links dump into "root"

Tags: apache-spark

I am running into many Q&A  in which links to `spark` docs lead to an uninspiring dead-end at "root" - for example http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MapWithStateDStream@stateSnapshots():org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[(KeyType,StateType  which gives us this *gem* :

[image]

The question containing that link is [How to access stateSnapshot in mapGroupsWithState or share the GroupState between streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479854/how-to-access-statesnapshot-in-mapgroupswithstate-or-share-the-groupstate-betwee):

and it is the first link shown in the question:

[image]

So this was just one example..  Is there a way to coerce the link/URL to resolve to the original intended content ?